# adding a custom link to a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress menu plugin that comes with a theme, unfortunately the theme was limited in that, it did only provide on menu, I wanted to add another menu to it. I have found where I wanted to add my link in the theme. I found that one menu provided by the theme

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(cs_users_profile_link($cs_page_id, 'gallery', $uid)); ?>" <?php echo force_balance_tags($data_toogle); ?>><i class="icon-suitcase5"></i> <?php _e('gallery', 'thematic'); ?></a>  
</li>
```

And duplicated that twice, but the problem if the link takes me to a page `http://foo.bar/?author=1`

Is there anyway I can modify this link so it takes me to a page found `http://foo.bar/playground` ?

Comment: can't you create another menu? In menues, is add menu missing?

Comment: else you can create a new menu through functions.php, Easy if you are using a custom theme or have created a child theme - 
This page explains how [menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

Comment: @Stender the site uses custom theme which was developed by a previous employer, and he has already hard coded the menu inside theme. as in (if role is user) {show this menus} ... I would've preferred to create menus from the dashboard but it is impossible I think]

Comment: what happens if you put this into functions? 
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

Does it not give you the means of editing it in the dashboard?

Comment: @Stender I went to http://example.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php and I  see a `Header Menu` on the bottom part of the page below Menu Settings. What should I do now?

Comment: you should be able to use the GUI to edit that menu - And then display with something like this : <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the href attribute of the link?

```
<li>
    <a href="http://foo.bar/playground"><i class="icon-suitcase5"></i> <?php _e('gallery', 'thematic'); ?></a>  
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, I can change the url, but I don't want to do that. It means everytime we change want to change the url we have to modify the code too. Isn't there another way to do this?

Comment: you can look for a page ID perhaps? `get_permalink( 123 )` where 123 is the page ID? or if the menu is managed in wp-admin you can simply use the menu manager there.